# How to extract value of column based on value change in other column python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have dataframe with two columns i want extract value of first column based on second column, if in last 3 rows of column 2 value change from 0 to any value then extract value of column 1.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'column1':[1,5,6,7,8,11,12,14,18,20],'column2':[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,256,256,0]})
print(df)
   column1  column2
0        1        0
1        5        0
2        6        1
3        7        1
4        8        0
5       11        0
6       12        0
7       14      256
8       18      256
9       20        0

out_put=pd.DataFrame({'column1':[20],'column2':[0]})

print(out_put)
   column1  column2
0       20        0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need check difference with last values to first in last 3 values of second column:

```
df1 = df.tail(3)
df2 = df1[df1['column2'].eq(0).view('i1').diff().eq(1)]

print (df2)
   column1  column2
9       20        0
```

**Details**:

```
#last 3 rows
print (df1)
   column1  column2
7       14      256
8       18      256
9       20        0

#compare second colum for equality
print (df1['column2'].eq(0))
7    False
8    False
9     True
Name: column2, dtype: bool

#convert mask to integers
print (df1['column2'].eq(0).view('i1'))
7    0
8    0
9    1
Name: column2, dtype: int8
```

---

```
#get difference
print (df1['column2'].eq(0).view('i1').diff())
Name: column2, dtype: int8
7    NaN
8    0.0
9    1.0
Name: column2, dtype: float64

#compare by 1
print (df1['column2'].eq(0).view('i1').diff().eq(1))
7    False
8    False
9     True
Name: column2, dtype: bool
```

And last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).